# NaN out of matrix multiplication?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, debugging, nan, matrix-multiplication

I have the code below for matrix formation out of an array and its multiplication.

But when I try to multiply two matrices like `mtp(matrix(2,2,[1,2,3,4]),matrix(2,2,[1,0,0,1]))` it returns `NaN` in all places.
Please help me out

```js
function matrix(m, n, arr) {
  var result = {};
  for (t = 1; t <= m; t++) {
    result[t] = {};
  };
  for (i = 1; i <= m; i++)
    for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) result[i][j] = arr[m * (i - 1) + j - 1];
  return {
    "result": result,
    "m": m,
    "n": n
  };
}

function mtp(a, b) {
  if (parseInt(a.n) != parseInt(b.m)) {
    return;
  } else {
    var result = [];
    var m = parseInt(a.m);
    var n = parseInt(b.n);
    var k = parseInt(a.n);
    for (i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
      for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        for (p = 1; p <= k; p++) {
          result[m * (i - 1) + j - 1] += (parseInt(a.result[i][p]) * parseInt(b.result[p][j]));
          console.log(parseInt(a.result[i][p]) * parseInt(b.result[p][j]))
        }
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(result, matrix(m, n, result).result);
}

mtp(matrix(2,2,[1,2,3,4]),matrix(2,2,[1,0,0,1]));
```

Comment: Aside: You dont need all those `parseInt` - everything is already numeric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define `result` it is an array of zero elements

```
var result = [];
```

When you try to add a number to an element of the array, that element is not defined, Adding any number to undefined gives you `NaN`. There are 2 ways to solve this, either initialize your array with the right length of zeros, or default it to zero during the sum. I've chosen the latter below,

```
result[m * (i - 1) + j - 1] = (result[m * (i - 1) + j - 1]||0) + (a.result[i][p] * b.result[p][j]);
// Note here ---------------------------------------------^
```

I've got rid of all the unnecessary `parseInt` calls.

```js
function matrix(m, n, arr) {
  var result = {};
  for (t = 1; t <= m; t++) {
    result[t] = {};
  };
  for (i = 1; i <= m; i++)
    for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) result[i][j] = arr[m * (i - 1) + j - 1];
  return {
    "result": result,
    "m": m,
    "n": n
  };
}

function mtp(a, b) {
  if (a.n != b.m) {
    return;
  } else {
    var result = [];
    var m = a.m;
    var n = b.n;
    var k = a.n;
    for (i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
      for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        for (p = 1; p <= k; p++) {
          result[m * (i - 1) + j - 1] = (result[m * (i - 1) + j - 1]||0) + (a.result[i][p] * b.result[p][j]);
          console.log(a.result[i][p] * b.result[p][j])       
        }
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(result, matrix(m, n, result).result);
}

mtp(matrix(2,2,[1,2,3,4]),matrix(2,2,[1,0,0,1]));
```

Comment: you just solved by biggest problem, thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

In your `mtp()` function the values of the elements inside your result array are uninitialized (that is, you've defined an array, but that array has no actual values or even a determined length), so in your inner loop when you `+=`, you're referencing a newly created array element which has no default value (and therefore is `undefined`), and adding some number to that undefined value.

An undefined value plus a number is not a number (`NaN`).  Try preinitializing your result array.

Comment: You probably mean to say 'the *values inside* the result array are uninitialized'? If you do that, then it's correct.

Comment: Almost a good answer, *+1* from me, however, in Javascript preinitialization of an array is not that necessary. A check for *undefined* is simpler.